# How to transfer decision boundary learned from scaled data to the original data (scaled back data)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I fitted SVM on scaled input data and right now I am trying to find a way to transfer decision boundary learned from scaled data to the original data (non-scaled data). How should I do that?

I used the following to plot the decision boundary:

```
svc0.fit(Xs, y)
plot_decision_regions(X=Xs, y=y ,clf=svc0,legend=2)
```

[image]

then I just scaled back data (svc0 is still fitted on scaled data), but decision boundary looks weird:

```
Xs_scaledback=scaler.inverse_transform(Xs) 

plot_decision_regions(X=Xs_scaledback,y=y,clf=svc0,legend=2)
```

[image]

I need to show the decision boundary on original (scaled back) data. How can I fix this?!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to combine your data scaling into the estimator?

Something like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

data_dict = load_iris()

X, y = data_dict['data'][:, :2], data_dict['target']

model = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), SVC())
model.fit(X,y) # You should do a train test split

def plot_decision_boundary(pred_func, X, y):
    # Set min and max values and give it some padding
    x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - .5, X[:, 0].max() + .5
    y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - .5, X[:, 1].max() + .5
    h = 0.01
    # Generate a grid of points with distance h between them
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    # Predict the function value for the whole gid
    Z = pred_func(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    # Plot the contour and training examples
    plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
    plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
    
    
plot_decision_boundary(model.predict, X, y)
```

> Partly adapted from https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_voting_decision_regions.html

Comment: Thanks Myccha. 
Data scaling in this case is implemented on a larger dataset (X_all) and Xs is a subset of X_all. I need to show decision boundary when I scaled back data which it is expected to look like the one in scaled data.

Comment: Can you try my code using plot_decision_boundary(make_pipeline(scaler,svc0).predict, Xs_scaledback)

Comment: Thank you! your approach was helpful. I figured it out.